# If two pieces of the same type of metal touch in outer space, they will bond together permanently?

Tags: space, metal

Is this true? And if so, why?
http://www.snapple.com/real-facts/cap-view/1003

Comment: Basically, sorta, Yes. There's a nice discussion of the phenomena over at the Space Exploration stack: How is the unwanted cold welding prevented in space? http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4169/how-is-the-unwanted-cold-welding-prevented-in-space

Comment: Thanks for the link! I would upvote your comment if I could but I don't have the reputation yet lol @WayfaringStranger

Comment: This question is better suited for the Space Exploration sister site, but if it was moved there, it would be marked as a duplicate of the question linked by Wayfaring Stranger ASAP.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not astronomy (as discussed above)